# Display content of large file in NSTextView

Tags: objective-c, performance, macos, file, nstextview

I'm trying to work with large files e.g. > 1Gb and NSTextView. Of course I do not want to load whole file into memory, but load only the "visible window" of lets say of 4mb. Does anyone tried this before? 
I tried to load 4mb window of file into the NSTextStorage but it is quite slow, when user is change scrollbar position the time spent for loading of next portion of data is noticeable and disturbing.
Is there some other way to deal with this kind of data loading?

Comment: What type of data are you handling? Pure text?

Comment: It will be attributed text (some simple coloring/bolding of found keywords).

Comment: I haven't work before with NSTextStorage os NSTextView, but you could consider two thing: Spliting your file into multiple files, so you will only load the specific text you want, and you could use a NSArray to store your file in the order you will need. Probably when you do another load it reads all the file. The other thing is to have this into Core Data.